# Android - activities lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

lets imagine this application like enclosed image. R stands for Root activity and A and B are other activities. A is for displaying of some list, B stands for displaying detail of some value. From R I can get by 4 buttons to 4 A activities. My question is, whether in this scenario is A activity initialized for each time or I would be using only one A activity among whole application. If user selects A in right top corner activity A, then displays detail B and then from detail B goes to another list (but based on A activity). Will he still got the same content from the first A or he can have "new" A activity with another list?

Here is the point - I will be having let's say hundred of activites. Lot of them are "forms" displaying some content, application will have about 50 variants of those forms. Can I make for each form one activity a reuse it again in my activity without having connections to past usage of this activity?

[image: Activites example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in your manifest if you want a single instance of your activity class

Comment: I am asking whether I can use multiple instances of one activity, so multiple instances are set as a Default?

Comment: @Hmyzak yup..each time you start an activity a new instance is created

Answer (score 2):

By default activities start over entirely every time you open them with a call to `startActivity()`.  If your activity starts a new activity, it will essentially be put on to an activity stack and is paused while the new activity starts.  If the user presses the back button, the last activity on the stack will resume as it left off (though I don't think this is 100% guaranteed as Android will kill off tasks as it needs resources so I wouldn't assume it).

So if you have this chain here:

`A->B->C->D`

where each letter represents a new activity with absolutely no flags or changes.

If the user is at `D` and presses the `back` button, `C` will resume.  `D` is popped from the stack.  If the user decides to go to activity `D` again, a new `D` will start as if it didn't happen (assuming you didn't save any persistent variables).  If the user presses `back` twice, the application will be at `B` where `C` and `D` are no gone.

You can manipulate this chain with various flags like `singleInstance` to keep its state, or `noHistory` to ensure it doesn't get put to the stack (meaning it will be skipped if the user presses `back`).

[Very detailed description of the various attributes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: Thaks for comment, so in my case, I am able to start 4 different instances A from R activity?

Comment: Are these the same activity but with different initialization parameters?

Either way, yes.  You can pass in parameters via the `putExtra()` method of the intent you use to start the `Activity`.  Then get the extras within your `Activity` by calling `getIntent().getExtras()`.  It will give you a `Bundle` that has the information you passed in.

Comment: What do you mean by inicialization parametres?

Comment: Values and data to give an activity so it can be set up in a particular way before the user sees it.